# Find $P(X^2+Y^2<1)$ if $X,Y$ are independent standard normal variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

### Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent $n(0,1)$ random variables.

#### (a) Find $P(X^2+Y^2<1)$

My solution:
since then are independent, the $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2}}$
then $P[X^2+Y^2]=\int\int F_{X,Y}$
I am not sure how to define the boundary of the integrals.

Comment: The integral is over all $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2<1$.  This is the unit disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral is over the open unit disk, hence if you switch to polar coordinates the result is
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\;rdrd\theta$$

Comment: the solution proposed in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937972/px2y21-of-two-independent-n0-1-random-variables/937984#937984 confused me.

Comment: I don't know why that answer has an extra $x^2+y^2$ in the integral. The second answer gets the same result as mine.

Comment: Indeed at least the second answer on the other page gets the correct answer -- but at what cost... Much better to follow the one-liner here!

Comment: Using the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ to cancel the $\int \cdots d\theta$, you are left with the Rayleigh distribution

Answer (score 0):

If X~N(0,1), then the pdf of $X^2$ is not the square of a normal pdf. Even if you integrate what you have, you'll get the wrong answer. In fact, $X^2$ has a chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you have found the joint pdf of (X,Y). However, if you want to find that of $X^2$ and $Y^2$, you can use the same rule of independence. You will find that the joint pdf of $(X^2,Y^2)$ is Gamma(1,2) = Exponential(2).